# What's wrong with Jsch and Maven?

Tags: maven, jsch

I try to use Jsch 0.1.44 together with Maven.

I have the following dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.44</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I run `mvn compile` maven looks normal and tells me that Jsch has been successful downloaded.

But when it comes to compile, the Jsch classes could not be found. If I look into my local repository I can see that the Jsch-jar has only a size of 3kb. If I open the jar file I can also see that there is only the META-INF folder.

So what is wrong here, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason the jar file in the central repository seems to be broken. 
The solution is to add another repository for Jsch to the pom.xml.

```
<repository>
    <id>Jsch</id>
    <url>http://jsch.sf.net/maven2/</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are different possibilities:

- You have used the correct Maven repository for `jsch` (seems to be this one: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.44-1), but the download stopped for whatever reason. This happens, and you have just to clear your local repository by deleting the directory for `jsch` or the the version only. It will be reloaded again.
- Perhaps you has misconfigured your remote repository for `jsch`, and `jsch` is hold somewhere, but not the library, only the meta data. I do not know if it is possible to see from which location you got the wrong library.

You should look at your `settings.xml` (for Maven or your user) and see if the repository is specified correctly.

You should check if the command

```
mvn dependency:get -DrepositoryUrl=http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ \
                   -DgroupId=com.jcraft -DartifactId=jsch -Dversion=0.1.44 \
                   -Dtransitive=false
```

works properly.

Comment: +1 and thanks for your answer. One comment on your last command. It doesn't work. Gives me `[ERROR] Could not find goal 'download' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:2.9`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I got the download wrong (Maven 1 only), and have corrected it, hope it works now. Seems like the fault was that the original did not contain the content :-)

Answer (score 4):

0.1.44 version is broken (it's only 3KB)

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.44

use http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.44-1 Instead

update your POM to this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.44-1</version>
</dependency>
```